# pyQT5 problems inserting dates in Sqlite table

Tags: pyqt5

I'm doing some test to understand how sqlite manage dates and times.
I created a very simple program to insert the current date and time into a table with 2 fields defined as 'Numeric' and 'Integer'. The issue I'm having is the record is inserted with the two fields empty and I don't understand why.
I  put below the code including the class to manage Sqlite connection. Thanks for any help

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery
from connect_SQLITE import Database
from datetime import datetime

currentDateTime = datetime.now()

db=Database()

InsertQuery = QSqlQuery()
InsertQuery.prepare("INSERT INTO Prova (dataPreventivo, dataPreventivo1) "
                "VALUES (?, ?)")
InsertQuery.bindValue(":dataPreventivo1", currentDateTime)
InsertQuery.bindValue(":dataPreventivo1", currentDateTime)
InsertQuery.exec()
db.commit_db()
```

connect_SQLITE.py

```
import sys
import sqlite3
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox, QLabel

class Database(object):

   con=QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
   con.setConnectOptions("detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES |                                                               sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES")
   con.setDatabaseName("/Users/MyUser/Documents/Micro/db/Micro.db")

   query=QSqlQuery()

   def __init__(self):

 # Try to open the connection and handle possible errors

      if not self.con.open():
         QMessageBox.critical(None,"App Name - Error!","Database Error: %s" %          self.con.lastError().databaseText(),)
         sys.exit(1)  
  

   def commit_db(self):
      self.con.commit()

   def close_db(self):
      self.con.close()

   def read_db(self, sqlstr, values, campi):
     self.query.prepare(sqlstr)
     for i in range(campi):
       self.query.addBindValue(values[i])
     self.query.exec() 
     return self.query

   def insert_db(self, sqlstr, values, campi):
     self.query.prepare(sqlstr)
     for i in range(campi):
       self.query.addBindValue(values[i])    
     Database.commit_db(self)
     return self.query
```

Comment: There are multiple problems: 1. it should be `VALUES(:dataPreventivo, :dataPreventivo1)`; 2. you're binding only one value (`dataPreventivo1`) twice; 3. `datetime.now()` is not a valid data type for the database, you should use `str(currentDateTime)`.

Comment: The binding of one value twice  (dataPreventivo1) was a typo. Your suggestion about using str(currentDateTime) works perfectly, thanks a lot